# what's the relationship between system signal and Com signal in autosar

Tags: autosar

what's the relationship between system signal and Com signal in autosar.?

for my knowledge, Com signal is configured in Com module in BasicSoftware

Answer (score 1):

`AUTOSAR_TPS_SystemTemplate` describes this in the chapter 5.2 DataMapping.

In short for a Sender/Receiver interface, the data elements (VariableDataPrototype) of a SWCs SenderReceiver port are mapped to SystemSignals and SystemSignalGroups, when the communication between two SWCs are crossing the ECU boundaries, because the SWCs are mapped to different ECUs (Inter-ECU communication).

The SystemSignalGroups are then mapped to ISignalGroups and SystemSignals to ISignals. These ISignals and ISignalGroups are mapped to ISignalIPdus and these are again mapped to Frames (e.g. CanFrames).

The ISignals and ISignalGroups are, what will be configured in EcuConfiguration in  Com or LdCom as ComSignals and ComSignalGroups.

The SystemSignals and SystemSignalGroups are, what the RTE configurator will do, to create the mapping of Rte_Read/Write functions to the calls of Com_Send/ReceiveSignal() / Com_Send/ReceiveSignalGroup().